# Is there any real world equivalent measurement to a Gomu Gomu?

Tags: one-piece

So we all know that [*Luffy*](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Monkey_D._Luffy) ate the Gomu Gomu no Mi Devil fruit and I found in the Gomu Gomu no Mi's [*wiki page*](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Gomu_Gomu_no_Mi) that Luffy is able to stretch a length of 72 Gomu Gomu's. So is there any real way to turn 72 Gomu Gomu's into a real world measurement of length?

[image]

Comment: Note that this was explained in an SBS (the very first one) which are usually more humorous than anything (but often still canon).

Comment: There are a bunch of [mathematics on how rubber elasticity is measured](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_elasticity), as well as [models that approximate elasticity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law). I doubt Oda have those in mind when writing OP though. Essentially, by giving vague answers like Gomu Gomu measurements, Luffy's power is just whatever the plot requires of him.

Comment: I would imagine a gomu gomu is about 10 feet because luffy can stretch pretty far

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No there is not.** At the [SBS of chapter 30](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_4#Chapter_30.2C_Page_90), Oda was asked how far Luffy's arm can stretch. He humorously replied

> O: Pretty far. Right now it can stretch about 72 Gomu Gomus. Luffy was telling me before how he wanted to try hard and reach 100 Gomu Gomus.

Later at the [SBS of chapter 47](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_6#Chapter_47.2C_Page_66), he was asked how many liters go into 1 Gomu Gomu and he replied

> O: Oh, you've come again! Gaimon's son. In "1 Gomu Gomu" there are "10 Fairy Tale Gomu Gomus". And in each "Fairy Tale Gomu Gomu" there are "10 Funky Gomu Gomus" so, in other words Luffy's arm can stretch around 7200 Funky Gomu Gomus. Understood?

When reading the SBS's you will see more of these funny replies and measurements come up, but you will never get a real world comparison.

The problem is that Luffy moves around too much. Oda was never able to measure how long one Gomu Gomu is. We will just have to trust Luffy's word, that it really is 72 Gomu Gomus and we can only imagine the real world distance.

Comment: I think either the quote is wrong, or Oda messed up with the maths. If 1 GG == 10 FTGG and 1 FTGG == 100 FGG, then 72 GG == 720 FTGG == 72000 FGG. He missed a zero.

Comment: @nolonar thanks for the comment. I quoted from the wikia where the numbers indeed dont add up. I checked again on the actual chapter and there it says (in english) that 1FTGG==10FGG instead of 100FGG. So unless someone shows me a japanese counter example i am assuming the wikia folks put a zero too much.